# Java Messages list of recipient not complete

Tags: java, email

I'm using javax.mail.Transport
I put the list of recipient as

```
msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, Address[] addresses);
```

If for ex I have two recipients test1 & test2, 
test1 will receive the mail with only his name in the TO filed 
and the same for test2 he will receive the mail with only his name in the TO field 
what I need is that every mail display the list of recipients in the TO filed

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Try  `new InternetAddress("testgroup:test1@gmail.com,test2@gmail.com;")`

Comment: Where do you run your code? In an App server?

Comment: This might be the specific of your mail server. Did you try to send the mail from a regular mail client like Thunderbird?